# The easyest way to create custom button

Tags: android

I need to create the following button:

[image]

"OK" text could be changed and depends on the text attribute of the button view. What is the easiest way to create the similar button? I was trying to create `9.patch` image, but it looks horrible :(

Comment: A TextView with a 9 patch drawable background and a compund drawable for the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[image: Final Product][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxdGZ.png)

The "easiest way" would be to not use a button. Instead use a horizontal LinearLayout with your check box image in an ImageView on the left and your "OK" text in a TextView on the right. Then set a custom background for each using xml drawables. Obviously this isn't actually a "Button" but provides the desired effect. The on click listener can be placed on the LinearLayout while manipulation of the text can be called by setting the text in the TextView.

XML for Right Side

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/wallet_holo_blue_light"/>
    <corners android:radius="20dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"/>
    <padding android:left="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="5dp" />
</shape>
```

XML for left side

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <corners android:radius="20dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
    <padding android:left="10dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp" />
</shape>
```

XML for layout_checkbutton

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/left"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done_24dp"
        android:tint="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/right"
        android:text="Okay"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Class is created through java code here with the ability to update the text.

```
public class CheckButton extends RelativeLayout {

    Context context;
    TextView text;

    public CheckButton(Context context){
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public CheckButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        inflate(context,R.layout.check_button,this);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    }

    public void setText(String string){
        text.setText(string);
    }

}
```

To implement this in an activity or fragment layout is simple...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_below="@+id/next"></FrameLayout>

    <dev.helix.testbed.CheckButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/okay"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="50dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Good idea, but it looks like some kind of "hack" ))

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "hack". For reusability, you can create a new layout XML specifically for the button and a class that inflates the layout so it acts as a single reusable unit. I can write an example of this later if it interests you. The "correct" way to do this would be to override the OnDraw() method of a custom view class that extends the Button class, but that is exponentially more difficult.

Comment: [This is a good tutorial on how to create custom views from a separate layout file](http://trickyandroid.com/protip-inflating-layout-for-your-custom-view/)

Comment: Edited to reflect full method.

Comment: @hellix, why there is imageview inside framelayout and then linearlayout inside relative?

Comment: just a bad habit of not cleaning my layouts... updated code works just as well. good catch